# Transitioning between view controllers with shared uiimage

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimationtransition

This is the transition I am trying to get: ViewControllerB slides up while UIImage, which originally was a subview of ViewControllerA remains on its place, then UIImage becomes a subview of ViewControllerB.

I've done some digging and it seems I have to use `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`, is that so? And how could I keep UIImage in the same place while ViewControllerB is sliding up?

Thank you.
[image: Desired result]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code at least?

Comment: Add `UIImageView` to window

Answer (score 0):

Better you create 2 view and 1 imageview in 1 viewcontroller. Create all views behind the imageView and everytime you wanna change the view, just add transition from bottom to top.